# Set of constant functions are uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Let $F=$ $\{$ $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $:$ $f$ is constant$ \} $. I must show that $F$ is uncountable.
Note, that for any $f \in F$, and any $c\in \mathbb{R}$, I will denote the constant function $f:$ [0,1] $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=c$ by $f_c$ .

Define a map $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow F$ by $g(x)= f_x$ then observe that
$g(a)=g(b)$ $\implies$ $f_a=f_b$. $f_a$ is the map defined on $[0,1]$ given by $f(x)=a$ and $f_b$ is the map defined on $[0,1]$ given by $h(x)=$ $b$. As the maps are equal, $a=b$ and so $g$ is injective, so $F$ must be uncountable.

Note: The map is also surjection and consequently a bijection, but showing it is indeed a bijection is not necessary.

Is the proof correct? What other easier ways are there to prove this?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Looks fine to me albeit a bit clunky.

Comment: May I see how you write it? Just so I could try to make my proofs look more elegant, please?

Comment: Typo:  You say $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ but it should be $g:\mathbb R \to F$

Comment: @lulu stole my thunder haha

Answer (score 1):

It would have been simpler to define a bijection $g:\,F\mapsto\Bbb R$ by $g(f):=f(0)$ for all $f\in F$.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up problem.
Let S be a subset of R.
Show there are |S| many constant functions from [0,1] into S.